# PrettyPrint feature does not work in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have been trying to leverage the PrettyPrint feature to display the result of my API that is using Apache Camel. Here is the context. I have this route in my code

```
// Route Definition for processing Health check request
                from("direct:processHealthCheckRequest")
                        .routeId("health")
                        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200))
                        .setBody(constant(healthCheckResponse));
```

When I'm using Postman to test my API, the display is in pretty mode even though it is not set to true, like so

```
{
  "status": "UP"
}
```

Now when I'm using the following code to set the PrettyPrint to false, I'm still getting the same result. It looks like the PrettyPrint feature is not working as it is supposed to

```
// Route Definition for processing Health check request
                from("direct:processHealthCheckRequest")
                        .routeId("health")
                        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200))
                        .setBody(constant(healthCheckResponse))
                        .unmarshal()
                        .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, HealthCheckResponse.class, false);
```

I'm expecting the result to be displayed on one line like here without changing the type from JSON to string.

```
{"status": "UP"}
```

Could someone please advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

I've bumped into the same issue always when manually setting the HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE header. I don't know why it technically happens - without it the HTTP response always returns proper JSON for me.

Setting CONTENT_TYPE header to application/json has solved it:

```
.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but it did not fix it, probably because I have a SpringBoot project and some config should be in the properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<removeHeaders id="removeHeaders_http*" pattern="CamelHttp*"/>
<setHeader headerName="Content-type" id="content_setHeader">
    <constant>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</constant>
</setHeader>
```

Same with Java DSL:

```
.removeHeaders("CamelHttp*")
.setHeader("Content-type", constant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
```

Comment: can you please suggest a solution with DSL java instead of XML notation?

Comment: .removeHeaders("CamelHttp*")                                                                     .setHeader("Content-type", constant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))

Answer (score 0):

The solution that finally worked was to set the following in my `application.properties` file.

```
camel.rest.data-format-property.prettyPrint=false
```

or not to provide that property at all.